# How to programmatically code an 'undo' function in Excel-Vba?

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

Is there anyway to code an undo function onto a CommandButton similar to the Excel's very own undo function?

Or a function which is capable of calling Ctrl-Z shortcut key.

Comment: There's a hiccup with this, in that when you call the VBA code, the undo stack is destroyed (make a spreadsheet, put some items on it, delete them, then call any VBA code to see what I mean).  I'm not sure if there's a way around this.  Another user had a similar issue, and I think you'd basically have to come up with a way to write changes to a file, and read them back again.

Comment: Minor point, but it is not true - or is no longer true - that calling _any_ VBA destroys the undo stack. Only VBA macros that make changes destroy the undo stack.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Add the command button to the worksheet and assign the following macro to it:

```
Sub UndoLastAction()

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .Undo
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With

End Sub
```

It can only undo the last action taken by the user and cannot undo VBA commands.

EDIT: If you need further undo capabilities see:

[Undo With Excel VBA - JKP](http://www.jkp-ads.com/Articles/UndoWithVBA00.asp)