# "Undo" history button clear after run macro excel

Tags: vba, excel, undo-redo

I have a macro that fires on the **"Worksheet_SelectionChange"** event. The macro validate data of one column, it changes the background color of the cell if its wrong.

The problem is after run the macro, it clears the history of changes (Ctrl Z) of all the document, even the history changes of other cells that I didnt validate.

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm such a turkey sometimes, here ya go: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7004754/how-to-programmatically-code-an-undo-function-in-excel-vba/7005226#7005226

Comment: Just saw this: http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/tip/undoing_a_vba_subroutine/

Comment: Is there anyway you can use Excel's built-in Data Validation and/or Conditional Formatting features to achieve the same functionality without using a macro? That seems to me to be the best solution if you can go that way.

Comment: I second @Excellll's suggestion

Comment: Thirded Exceellll's suggestion. While I normally like J Walk's tips, I'm not a fan of using arrays to hold prior data, xl app settings etc. It is far more robust to store info in a hidden sheet

Comment: @Remou while using the `.OnUndo` method described allows undoing the actions of the Sub itself, the Undo history is still cleared. AFAIK there is no way around that.

Comment: Worth noting, the undo history only gets cleared by the macro if it _actually_ makes changes. If you're ok with losing Undo history sometimes but not all the time, be sure to wrap your macro in If statements that ensure the worksheet really needs to change.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the others have stated, there is not way to stop a worksheet-changing macro from clearing the undo stack.

As another side-effect, you can't undo the macro either without writing your own Undo routine, which can be a huge hassle.

Here's to hoping MS changes this in the future.

Answer (score 5):

I had this issue and wound up having to create custom undo functionality. 
It works very similar to the native undo except for the following. I am sure they can be handled with a little more attention.

1) Custom undo does not undo formatting. Only text.

2) Custom undo goes all the way to end of the custom stack. Once this happens the stack is cleared and it does not toggle between the last two items like in the native undo functionality.

2.1)  Does not have REDO functionality.

[Download a working copy of this code.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1YKXw12gaWYYzBwcjNMckhRWHM/view?usp=sharing)

[VBAProject Layout Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OU8zv.png)

Module UndoModule

```
Public UndoStack() As UndoStackEntry
Private Const UndoMaxEntries = 50

Public Sub SaveUndo(ByVal newUndo As UndoStackEntry)

    'Save the last undo object
    If Not newUndo Is Nothing Then
        Call AddUndo(newUndo)
    End If

End Sub

Public Sub Undo()

    'Appy last undo from the stack and remove it from the array
    Dim previousEdit As UndoStackEntry
    Set previousEdit = GetLastUndo()
    If Not previousEdit Is Nothing Then
        Dim previousEventState As Boolean: previousEventState = Application.EnableEvents
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Range(previousEdit.Address).Select
        Range(previousEdit.Address).Value = previousEdit.Value
        Application.EnableEvents = previousEventState

        Call RemoveLastUndo
    End If

End Sub

Private Function AddUndo(newUndo As UndoStackEntry) As Integer

    If UndoMaxEntries < GetCount() Then
        Call RemoveFirstUndo
    End If

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    ReDim Preserve UndoStack(UBound(UndoStack) + 1)
    Set UndoStack(UBound(UndoStack)) = newUndo

    AddUndo = UBound(UndoStack)

ExitFunction:
    Exit Function

ErrorHandler:
    ReDim UndoStack(0)
    Resume Next

End Function

Private Function GetLastUndo() As UndoStackEntry

    Dim undoCount As Integer: undoCount = GetCount()
    If undoCount > 0 Then
        Set GetLastUndo = UndoStack(undoCount - 1)
    End If

End Function

Private Function RemoveFirstUndo() As Boolean

    On Error GoTo ExitFunction

    RemoveFirstUndo = False
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To UBound(UndoStack)
        Set UndoStack(i - 1) = UndoStack(i)
    Next i
    ReDim Preserve UndoStack(UBound(UndoStack) - 1)
    RemoveFirstUndo = True

    ExitFunction:
       Exit Function

End Function

Private Function RemoveLastUndo() As Boolean

    RemoveLastUndo = False
    Dim undoCount As Integer: undoCount = GetCount()
    If undoCount > 1 Then
        ReDim Preserve UndoStack(undoCount - 2)
        RemoveLastUndo = True
    ElseIf undoCount = 1 Then
        Erase UndoStack
        RemoveLastUndo = True
    End If

End Function

Private Function GetCount() As Long

    GetCount = 0
    On Error Resume Next
    GetCount = UBound(UndoStack) + 1

End Function
```

Class Module UndoStackEntry

```
 Public Address As String
 Public Value As Variant
```

Also needed to attach to the following events on the WORKBOOK Excel object.

```
Public Sub WorkbookUndo()

    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.PageUndo

ErrExit:
    Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
    On Error GoTo ErrExit
    Application.Undo
    Resume ErrExit

End Sub
```

Finally each sheet where you require undo to work should have the following code attached to its events.

```
Dim tmpUndo As UndoStackEntry
Dim pageUndoStack() As UndoStackEntry

Private Sub OnSelectionUndoCapture(ByVal Target As Range)
    Set tmpUndo = New UndoStackEntry
    tmpUndo.Address = Target.Address
    tmpUndo.Value = Target.Value
    UndoModule.UndoStack = pageUndoStack
End Sub

Private Sub OnChangeUndoCapture(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.OnKey "^{z}", "ThisWorkbook.WorkbookUndo"
    Application.OnUndo "Undo Procedure", "ThisWorkbook.WorkbookUndo"

    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range(tmpUndo.Address)) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Value <> tmpUndo.Value Or Empty = Target.Value Then
            UndoModule.UndoStack = pageUndoStack
            Call UndoModule.SaveUndo(tmpUndo)
            pageUndoStack = UndoModule.UndoStack
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub PageUndo()
    UndoModule.UndoStack = pageUndoStack
    Call UndoModule.Undo
    pageUndoStack = UndoModule.UndoStack
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    'Stash away the value of the first cell in the selected range
    On Error Resume Next

    Call OnSelectionUndoCapture(Target)
    oldValue = Target.Value
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    On Error Resume Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    If tmpUndo.Value <> Target.Value Then
        'Do some stuff
    End If

    Call OnChangeUndoCapture(Target)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: But what about Redo Action?

Comment: There is a better solution that handles also changes in format,  in http://www.jkp-ads.com/Articles/UndoWithVBA00.asp