# Excel VBA to automatically capitalise causing error when pasting

Tags: excel, vba

The code below is causing an error when I paste information onto the sheet.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim A1 As Range
    Set A1 = Range("A:I")
    If Not Intersect(Target, A1) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
            Target.Value = UCase(Target.Value)
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

The code is specific to the sheet (right click on tab an view code).

Could you please advise on how to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have any more information on the error that is being thrown?

Answer (score 3):

Loop over the intersection cells if they exists:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim A1 As Range, intr As Range, r As Range
    Set A1 = Range("A:I")
    Set intr = Intersect(A1, Target)
    If Not intr Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
            For Each r In intr
                r.Value = UCase(r.Value)
            Next r
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Without error control, this will still have issue if *r* contains a worksheet error.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for that. Just one issue, the date when copied is changing from 17/12/2018 to 12/17/2018. Don't think it was doing this before. Any ideas?

Comment: It is questionable whether the OP needs `For Each r In intr` or `For Each r In Target`. But I can see the logic in both of them.

Comment: @JasonF You could check to see if the data type of r.value is a date after you change it to upper case and then change the number format to whatever you want

Answer (score 0):

The error is because of `Target.Value = UCase(Target.Value)` is not suitable for multiple cells. Thus a loop is needed:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    On Error GoTo WorksheetChange_Error

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Dim A1 As Range
    Set A1 = Range("A:I")

    If Not Intersect(Target, A1) Is Nothing Then
            Dim myCell As Range
            For Each myCell In Target.Cells
                myCell = UCase(myCell)
            Next
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub

WorksheetChange_Error:

    Application.EnableEvents = True
    MsgBox Err.Description

End Sub
```

The error handler is used to reset the `EnableEvents = True`, if some kind of unexpected error comes.

Comment: Hi Vityata. Thanks so much. That works great. I'm not sure this is related but there's a new issue when copying information onto this worksheet now. The date is changing fomr 17/12/2018 to 12/17/2018. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Also, with this update, the undo function appears to have been disabled. Any suggestions?

Comment: @JasonF - This is for the undo - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7798575/undo-history-button-clear-after-run-macro-excel

Comment: @JasonF - to fix the date, manually record a macro, in which you get the correct date. Then use the recorded code to format your VBA.