# Highlighting Cells That Change

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2010

I would like to highlight any cell that changes within an Excel sheet yellow. Currently, I have the following code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
End Sub
```

This works very well and serves the intended purpose, but has one glaring issue. I cannot revert the changes (ctrl + z does not work) and if I change the cell back to it's original content, the cell remains yellow, as it is being recognized as a change, leading to an endless loop. I can manually select 'no fill' to remove the yellow fill, but I would like this to be automatic. In case I were to make a mistake in the sheet and want to go back to the cell's original content, I would like the cell to have no fill without manually doing so.

Is there any way around this issue?

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7805738

Comment: Not sure what you're doing, but perhaps: duplicate your data sheet, then on the copy, set up conditional formatting, where say `=Sheet1Copy!A1<>Sheet1!A1`?  But that'll show a difference between sheets, not *necessarily* updated cells between saves/changes while you're working.

Answer (score 3):

This might be better for your usage, using `Worksheet_SelectionChange()` instead of `Worksheet_Change()` in 2 steps:

1. In the `ThisWorkbook` private module, define a public member gOldTarget. And we add code to highlight the `Selection` with focus immediately after openning Excel doc in `Workbook_Open()`. As well as to delete the highliting when quitting Excel in `Workbook_BeforeClose()`. So that the yellow cell setting is not saved in the final Excel doc.

```
Option Explicit

Public gOldTarget As Range

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
  If (TypeName(Selection) = "Range") Then
    Selection.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
    Set gOldTarget = Selection
  End If
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
  '
  ' restore the old cell before saving into doc.xlsm:
  '
  If (Not gOldTarget Is Nothing) Then
    gOldTarget.Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone
  End If

End Sub
```

2. At the second step, we add code in `Worksheet` private module, highlighting dynamically the ActiveCell/Selection, as you want:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
  '
  ' highlight the current cell:
  '
  Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
  '
  ' restore the old cell:
  '
  If (Not ThisWorkbook.gOldTarget Is Nothing) Then
    ThisWorkbook.gOldTarget.Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone
  End If
  
  '
  ' save the current target:
  '
  Set ThisWorkbook.gOldTarget = Target
End Sub
```

With Worksheet_SelectionChange(), it highlights the current cell with focus. When you quit the cell the highliting is suppressed.

[image]

[image]

Ref. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.selectionchange

Answer (score 2):

Global variables are frowned upon in programming but this is one area where you can use one to your advantage:

(i) declare the variable at the start of the worksheet module, e.g.

```
Public prevTarget As String
```

(ii) initialise it, either manually in the *Immediate Window*, or programatically in a `Workbook_Open()` procedure, e.g.

```
Sheet1.prevTarget="A1"
```

(iii) update your Worksheet_Change() procedure

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Count <> 1 Then Exit Sub
    Range(prevTarget).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
    Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
    prevTarget = Target.Address
End Sub
```

[image: screenshot illustrating code placement]

**Edited to add history-inclusive code**

(i) Declare 2 public variables at the start of the worksheet module, e.g.

```
Public prevTarget As String, logCount As Long
```

(ii) Declare a 3rd public variable at the start of *an inserted module*, e.g.

```
Public history() As String
```

(iii) Update the Worksheet_Change() procedure as follows

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Count <> 1 Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    logCount = logCount + 1
    ReDim Preserve history(1 To 2, 1 To logCount)
    Dim newVal As String
    newVal = Target.Formula
    Application.Undo
    history(1, logCount) = Target.Address
    history(2, logCount) = Target.Formula
    Target.Formula = newVal
    Target.Offset(1, 0).Select  'replicate the effect of cursor movement on Enter (prevented by call to Undo method)
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Range(prevTarget).Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone
    Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
    prevTarget = Target.Address
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

and, whenever you want to view this history, you can execute use this

```
Sub historyLog()
    ActiveCell.Resize(UBound(history, 2), 2).Value2 = Application.Transpose(history)
End Sub
```

If you make a lot of changes in quick succession then you will notice that data entry is now 'sticky', but that is inevitable because of the call to the `Application.Undo()` method, which is required to maintain the change history.

[image: screenshot of new sheet-level code]
[image: screenshot of module-level code]