# Enable Undo when AppSheetChanged is implemented in Excel Add-in

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, add-in, undo

I just noticed that when AppSheetChanged event handler is implemented in Excel add-in, the Ctrl-Z (undo) functionality does not work. Any idea on how to make this work?

Comment: Could you please explain this with better details?

Answer (score 4):

Changes made by a macro/add-in cannot be undone with Edit: Undo. There are a few threads on StackOverflow that discuss this. [Here's one.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7004754/how-to-programmatically-code-an-undo-function-in-excel-vba)

Here's a [page from Microsoft](https://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/undo-redo-or-repeat-an-action-HP001216394.aspx) that states "In Excel, macros can clear all items from the undo list."

You can build in your own Undo functionality; here's an example of how to do it:  [Undo With Excel VBA - JKP](http://www.jkp-ads.com/Articles/UndoWithVBA00.asp)