# how to create a undo clear all button in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have made it clear all button but I'm having issues making a undo clear all button
code for a clear all button in VBA

```
private sub commandbutton1_click
Sheets ("examplesheet").range ("a1:a3").value = ""
```

can somebody help me make a undo button for this example in the instance that I accidentally cleared the whole form?

Comment: Ben, see the answer to [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7004754/how-to-programmatically-code-an-undo-function-in-excel-vba).

Comment: Sorry, the post answer that I suggested deals only with undoing non-VBA actions. Instead, take a look at the answer described **[here](http://www.jkp-ads.com/Articles/UndoWithVBA00.asp)**.

Comment: A little over my head to be honest could you provide a example code for the code provided?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function that does something when You click the undo button.

Here is an example that uses a sheet called `Undo` to store the info required for the undo. The sheet can be hidden to make it cleaner.

```
Sub Test()
  ClearCell Cells(1, 1)
End Sub

Sub ClearCell(R As Range)
  Sheets("Undo").Range("A1") = R.Worksheet.Name
  Sheets("Undo").Range("A2") = R.Address
  Sheets("Undo").Range("A3") = R.Text
  R.Clear
  Application.OnUndo "Undo button text", "MyUndo"
End Sub

Sub MyUndo()
  Sheets(Sheets("Undo").Range("A1").Text).Range(Sheets("Undo").Range("A2").Text) = Sheets("Undo").Range("A3").Text
End Sub
```

You can refine it by managing a queue of actions as explained in the document suggested by chuff's comment