# Disable cut, copy, paste menu items for Excel 2013

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to disable the **cut, copy, paste** menu items form the header menu of Excel 2013.

I think that the solution suggested [here](http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=373) works for Excel 2000, 2003 and 2007, but not for Excel 2013 because my cut, copy, paste menu items are still enabled.

[image]

The part of the code that isn't working is:

```
'Activate/deactivate cut, copy, paste and pastespecial menu items
Call EnableMenuItem(21, Allow) ' cut
Call EnableMenuItem(19, Allow) ' copy
Call EnableMenuItem(22, Allow) ' paste
Call EnableMenuItem(755, Allow) ' pastespecial
```

Comment: What part doesn't work?

Comment: I updated my question to explain what is not working.

Comment: Did you put a msgbox or something to make sure it runs this code

Comment: Yes I set a breakpoint.

Comment: If you cannot disable them, how about reversing them? Basically, I am proposing to catch the event and immediately issue an UNDO command. http://www.jkp-ads.com/Articles/CatchPaste.asp  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7004754/how-to-programmatically-code-an-undo-function-in-excel-vba